# List<Model> doesn't contain definition SingleOrDefaultAsync and accessible extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

when I try to get the single record into a model using `SingleOrDefaultAsync`, it shows an error

> List<Model> doesn't contain definition SingleOrDefaultAsync and  accessible extension method

```
public class MemoryRepository 
{
    private List<Genre> _genres;
    public MemoryRepository() //Constructor
    {
        _genres = new List<Genre>()
        { new Genre(){Id=1,GenreName="Comedy"},
          new Genre(){Id=2,GenreName="Action"}
        };
    }
    

    public async  Task<Genre> GetGenreById(int Id)
    {
       return await  _genres.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == Id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SingleOrDefaultAsync` and similar `~Async` methods are from Entity Framework Core and can be used to asynchronously query the database. They are used when working with an `IQueryable`, which is an abstraction to mean “things that can be queried“.

[Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) and other in-memory collections (e.g. arrays) are *not* queryable, since operations on them happen by working with the collection itself. Instead, they are *enumerable*, implementing `IEnumerable`, which makes them usable with the standard synchronous LINQ methods.

So you can just use the synchronous `SingleOrDefault` instead of the asynchronous `SingleOrDefaultAsync` here. This also means that you no longer need to await the result and the method can return synchronously as well:

```
// return type is changed to reflect a synchronous result
public Genre GetGenreById(int Id)
{
   return _genres.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
}
```

If you need your method to still return a `Task<Genre>` (e.g. if you need to implement an interface that is meant for asynchronous usage), then you can use `Task.Result` to wrap your synchronous result inside a task:

```
// note that there is no `async` here
public Task<Genre> GetGenreById(int Id)
{
   return Task.FromResult(_genres.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using it `.SingleOrDefault` Or `.FirstOrDefault()` Like below:-

```
...

return _genres.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
```

Or

```
...

return _genres.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
```

It will resolve your issue.

Comment: As you mentioned, this isn't asynchronous, so the `await` is redundant.

Comment: @HenryTwist My mistake, I updated my answer.